# EclipseRCP - Multiple Visible-When CoreExpressions to HandledMenuItem?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

In my *plugin.xml* I have defined multiple restrictions like:

```
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
   <definition id="my.stuff.readAccess1">
      <test>...</test>
   </definition>
   <definition id="my.stuff.readAccess2">
      <test>...</test>
   </definition>
</extension>
```

In my *fragment.e4xmi* file I would like to use multiple of these for a simple *HandledMenuItem* as a *Visible-When Expression* with a conjuction, is that possible somehow?

My issue is that I have many roles and other restrictions (this menu should be seen only in a specific perspective, etc.), and having to create a *CoreExpression* for all the menu items one-by-one seems a bit cumbersome.

Any hints if that could be avoided? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only specify the one core expression, but you can combine other expressions using `and` and `or`:

```xml
  <definition
        id="my.stuff.readAccess1and2">
       <and>
          <reference
                 definitionId="my.stuff.readAccess1">
          </reference>
          <reference
                 definitionId="my.stuff.readAccess2">
           </reference>
      </and>
  </definition>
```

Comment: Cool, seems a legit solution, gonna try it tomorrow.